# Internet Speed fast after restart, but then slowing down to 6.7 MBPs

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, performance, internet

I'm pretty sure my issue has been adressed somewhere else, but I just can't filter out all the other "slow internet" issues.

My issue is: When I do a fresh restart on my computer, I get 50 MBPs internet speed (the max my connection can do) immediately after the restart. But after some time, this slows down to 6.7 MBPs, and stays that way until I restart the machine. However, other devices like my iPhone continue to work at 50 MBPs.

- My internet speed test is fast.com.
- My PC is a Lenovo T14, running on Windows 10 19044.1889.
- My Wifi device is a built in MediaTek Wi-Fi 6 MT7921 Wireless LAN Card, running on driver 3.0.1.1198.
- My Wifi AP is Fritz!Box 7530 running on Fritz!OS 07.29.
- My distance between Computer and Device is about 3 meters.
- The fritz.box DSL graph does not show any significant network traffic coming in or going out.
- The fritz.box is set to choose all Wifi settings automatically.
- The Wifi speed fritz.box shows change continuously, but always are in the range of download > 100 and upload > 50.
- The Wifi connection details are: [fritz box wifi connection details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luty6.png)
- Another Lenovo PC shows the same behaviour, although not at the same time.
- Other devices like iPhone, iPad etc do not show any connection speed problems at the same time.
- In a different network, I can not see the same issue with the PC.
- When the PC does not have anything using internet resources, the speed test always shows around 6.7 MBPs. If there is internet usage going on, it's slower.
- Internet usage on the PC is slow in every app, not just the browser. Teams is just as slow.
- There ARE VPN software things running on the PC, but they are turned off, and they are not in a different state right after the restart, when the machine is still fast.

ANY ideas about what to do, to check..?

Marco

Comment: The first link when [searching for "MediaTek Wi Fi 6 MT7921"](https://www.google.com/search?q=MediaTek+Wi-Fi+6+MT7921) leads to a download of a newer driver version `22.30.1.1339`. Try that - upgrading my wi-fi drivers (of a different model) has helped me with degrading connection speeds.

Comment: Are you getting lots of errors perhaps ?

Answer (score 1):

It's the 2.4 GHz band.

After writing the post I actually noticed, that my iPhone turned to slow Internet, which has never happened before. I checked the Network overview, and noticed, that it's on the 2.4 GHz band.

Turned the 2.4 GHz of - and all devices clocked 50 GBPs.